# Python plot groupby.mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mean

I have the dataframe below called df1_df2:

```
IdDeviceTypeNameDevice  IdBox   IdDeviceValue   DateDeviceValue   ValueDeviceValue weekday     hour          value
IdDevice                                    
119 48  Chaudière Maud Ferrand  4   536448  2015-11-27 17:54:00     On          4               17           1
119 48  Chaudière Maud Ferrand  4   536449  2015-11-27 17:54:00     Off         4               17           0
119 48  Chaudière Maud Ferrand  4   536450  2015-11-27 17:54:00     On          4               17           1
119 48  Chaudière Maud Ferrand  4   536451  2015-11-27 17:54:00     Off         4               17           0
119 48  Chaudière Maud Ferrand  4   536453  2015-11-27 18:09:00     On          4               18           1
```

I would like to group by the values (in the 'value' column, for each device type (in the 'IdDeviceType' column)  in a plot, that would have  the ' 'hour' column as the axis.

The idea is to see on a plot when a heater or another device  is on or off given the hours during the day.

This is what I've done:

```
df1_df2['value']= df1_df2['ValueDeviceValue']
df1_df2.loc[df1_df2['ValueDeviceValue'].str.lower()=='on','value'] = 1.
df1_df2.loc[df1_df2['ValueDeviceValue'].str.lower()=='off','value']= 0.

def my_plot(df,devids,idboxes):
    df = df[df['IdDeviceType'].isin(devids)]
    print (set(df.value.values))

    vals = [df[df['IdBox']== idb].groupby('hour')['value'].mean() for idb in idboxes]
    for val in vals : 
        plt.plot(val)
```

When I test it:

```
my_plot(df1_df2, [48], [4, 5])
```

I get the error message below. It looks like I cannot `group.by.mean` because the value column is not recognized as numerical.

---

```
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-447-75ef0a27eb5e> in <module>()
----> 1 my_plot(df1_df2,[48],[4,5])

<ipython-input-445-b5ff09b606b7> in my_plot(df, devids, idboxes)
  4     print (set(df.value.values))
  5 
  6     vals = [df[df['IdBox']== idb].groupby('hour')['value'].mean()     for idb in idboxes]
  7     for val in vals :
  8         #print (val)

<ipython-input-445-b5ff09b606b7> in <listcomp>(.0)
  4     print (set(df.value.values))
  5 
  6     vals = [df[df['IdBox']== idb].groupby('hour')['value'].mean() for idb in idboxes]
  7     for val in vals :
  8         #print (val)

/Users/chloegiraut/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in mean(self)
962         """
963         try:
964             return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
965         except GroupByError:
966             raise

/Users/chloegiraut/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-      packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how,     numeric_only)
763 
764         if len(output) == 0:
765             raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
766 
767         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output, names)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the value column as a number you can:

```
# get the On/Off string as 1/0
df1_df2['value'] = (
    df1_df2['ValueDeviceValue'].str.lower() == 'on').astype(np.uint8)
```

**Test Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [x.strip().split() for x in """
    IdDevice IdDeviceType NameDevice IdBox IdDeviceValue DateDeviceValue ValueDeviceValue weekday hour
    119 48  Chaud 4   536448  2015-11-27T17:54:00     On          4 17
    119 48  Chaud 4   536449  2015-11-27T17:54:00     Off         4 17
    119 48  Chaud 4   536450  2015-11-27T17:54:00     On          4 17
    119 48  Chaud 4   536451  2015-11-27T17:54:00     Off         4 17
    119 48  Chaud 4   536453  2015-11-27T18:09:00     On          4 18
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
df1_df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:], columns=data[0])
for column in 'IdDevice IdDeviceType IdBox IdDeviceValue'.split():
    df1_df2[column] = pd.to_numeric(df1_df2[column])

# get the On/Off string as 1/0
df1_df2['value'] = (
    df1_df2['ValueDeviceValue'].str.lower() == 'on').astype(np.uint8)

def my_plot(df, devids, idboxes):
    dev_idx = df['IdDeviceType'].isin(devids)
    df = df[dev_idx]
    print (set(df.value.values))
    vals = [df[df['IdBox'] == idb].groupby('hour')['value'].mean()
            for idb in idboxes]
    for val in vals:
        print()
        print(val)

my_plot(df1_df2, [48], [4, 5])
```

**Results:**

```
set([0, 1])

hour
17    0.5
18    1.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

Series([], Name: value, dtype: uint8)
```

Comment: awesome stephen! it works but there is one error message

Comment: YOur code that i plugged in my notebook. It says                                         data = [x.strip().split() for x in """
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]

Comment: For these two first lines it says : 
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: do I have to out something between both """ and """?

Comment: That part of the code is just generating a data frame.  So, yes you need something between the """'s or use your data...

Comment: to change the graph design, I added

Comment: .plot.bar(title=title, color='blue', linewidth=0.3)
    plt.axis([0, 24, 0, 1])
    plt.xlabel('hour')
    plt.ylabel('ON')
    plt.show()

Comment: def my_plot(df, devids, idboxes):
    dev_idx = df['IdDeviceType'].isin(devids)
    df = df[dev_idx]
    print (set(df.value.values))
    vals = [df[df['IdBox'] == idb].groupby('hour')['value'].mean()                            
            for idb in idboxes] . plt.bar(title=title, color='blue', linewidth=0.3)
    plt.axis([0, 24, 0, 1])
    plt.xlabel('hour')
    plt.ylabel('ON')
    for val in vals:
        print()
        print(val)

my_plot(df1_df2, [48], [4, 5])  but it is not working

Comment: Hey Stephen,  now when i type my_plot(df1_df2, [48], [4, 5]) it shows me an array and not a plot anymore. How can I convert it to a plot?

Comment: Compare your function and mine.  I changed the plot to a print to make my debug easier.  Change it back.  :-)  Glad it got going for you.  Cheers.

Comment: I saw this change but even the print now returns me an array

Comment: `plt.plot(val.values)`

Comment: that's what i tried before but it says that name 'val' is not defined or function has no plot method

Comment: Did you put it in the for loop?  `for val in vals: plt.plot(val.values)`

Comment: yes, not working . I just don't get why it was working yesterday night and now it is an array. I think the formula df1_df2['value'] = (
    df1_df2['ValueDeviceValue'].str.lower() == 'on').astype(np.uint8) is not working properly because my column value is on/off or a number, so when I do this I lose all the values that are numbers, that are converted to 0.

Comment: works very well, thx a million. If I wanted to add a second plot on the same graph for a another IdDeviceType, how could I do?

Comment: Would suggest you should ask another question.  And if this answer was useful would appreciate an accept, and an upvote.  cheers.

Comment: of course, let me try to find how to do that but obviously!